# How many distinct words can be formed from the letters of the word BHOPAL, such that at least 2 consonants always come together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This first approach i used is quite simple, as we can see there are 4 consonants and only 2 vowels so no matter how we arrange the letter, at least two consonants are always bound to come together, so the total number of permutations is simply 6! or 720.

But, i thought of using a different approach:

I grouped together any two consonants, so the other four letters can be permuted in 4! different ways.
also the pair of consonants that we grouped together can be permuted in 4*3 ways.

Now, the pair of consonants itself can occupy 5 different places i.e.
CC_ _ _ _
_ CC_ _ _
_ _CC _ _
_ _ _CC _
_ _ _ _CC

but, to get rid of repetitions of words like 'BHP0AL' that are counted in both first and second line, i confined one place before the pair to be a vowel i.e.
CC_ _ _ _
V CC_ _ _
_ V CC _ _
_ _ V CC _
_ _ _ V CC

but on adding up all the permutations i get 864, not 720, what did i do wrong?

Comment: why dont you just try **all arangements - all consonants are separated**